# How can I convert this D3 multi-series line chart x-axis to use sequential numbers instead of date values?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying convert [this chart](http://jsfiddle.net/3uo5bc5g/1/) I made, disregard the styles, using Highcharts, to [this](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955) D3 multi-line chart.

This is the code for the d3 viz.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.axis--x path {
  display: none;
}

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

</style>
<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 20, right: 80, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," +  margin.top + ")");

var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y%m%d");

var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]),
    y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]),
    z = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

var line = d3.line()
    .curve(d3.curveBasis)
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.temperature); });

d3.tsv("data.tsv", type, function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  var cities = data.columns.slice(1).map(function(id) {
    return {
      id: id,
      values: data.map(function(d) {
        return {date: d.date, temperature: d[id]};
      })
    };
  });

  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));

  y.domain([
    d3.min(cities, function(c) { return d3.min(c.values, function(d) { return d.temperature; }); }),
    d3.max(cities, function(c) { return d3.max(c.values, function(d) { return d.temperature; }); })
  ]);

  z.domain(cities.map(function(c) { return c.id; }));

  g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

  g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
      .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", "0.71em")
      .attr("fill", "#000")
      .text("Temperature, ºF");

  var city = g.selectAll(".city")
    .data(cities)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "city");

  city.append("path")
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); })
      .style("stroke", function(d) { return z(d.id); });

  city.append("text")
      .datum(function(d) { return {id: d.id, value: d.values[d.values.length - 1]}; })
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.value.date) + "," + y(d.value.temperature) + ")"; })
      .attr("x", 3)
      .attr("dy", "0.35em")
      .style("font", "10px sans-serif")
      .text(function(d) { return d.id; });
});

function type(d, _, columns) {
  d.date = parseTime(d.date);
  for (var i = 1, n = columns.length, c; i < n; ++i) d[c = columns[i]] = +d[c];
  return d;
}

</script>
```

I would like to keep the data in a tsv and just convert the x-axis from using dates to using the raw numbers seen in the Highchart series. So instead of city, date, and temperature it would be batter, game number, and slugging percentage. I would also like to make it so that the lines end, like in the Highchart example, once there is no corresponding value, and not just have the line dip down to 0.  It would also be nice if I could keep the hover effect from the Highchart example.

Unfortunately, I have little idea in how to achieve this.  I know that I have to use a different function than the parseTime function currently in the script but that's about as far as I've gotten.

Answer (score 1):

Change your scale to:

```
var x = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, width])
```

And don't parse to a date:

```
function type(d, _, columns) {
  d.date = +d.date;
  for (var i = 1, n = columns.length, c; i < n; ++i) d[c = columns[i]] = +d[c];
  return d;
```

}